# Is there a way for a client to detect that the connection is successfully opened?

Tags: rsocket

My server can reject the setup of a client. This can be detected on the client with RSocket.onClose().
But is there a way to detect that the connection was successfully opened, i.e. the server accepted the setup payload?
I would like something such as onOpened() which would be triggered when both server and client acceptors succeeded.

If I run the code below, the acceptor of the client is called even though the server rejected the client setup, so I can't use this.

```
    SocketAcceptor serverAcceptor = (setup, sendingSocket) ->
        Mono.error(new RuntimeException("Setup rejected"));

    RSocketServer.create(serverAcceptor)
        .bind(TcpServerTransport.create("localhost", 7000))
        .subscribe();

    SocketAcceptor clientAcceptor = (setup, sendingSocket) -> {
      logger.debug("Accepted");
      return Mono.just(new RSocket() {});
    };

    RSocket socket = RSocketConnector.create()
        .acceptor(clientAcceptor)
        .connect(TcpClientTransport.create("localhost", 7000)).block();
```